# When an NFS mount disappears, Finder hangs

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, nfs

I mount a VM's drive over NFS. I use the command

```
sudo mount host:/home/path /home
```

to mount the path on the VM to my `/home` directory (I do this to match the directories for sanity reasons).

The problem is when I shut down the VM without unmounting, Finder and most applications hang for a few minutes, until the OS realizes the drive is unreachable.

Are there options when mounting to keep this from happening?

Comment: Probably not – this is just a Finder "bug". I've seen it hang for quite a few reasons when waiting for drives to become available or realizing that network shares have suddenly become disconnected. Maybe you could work around it by scripting the VM shutdown so that the share is unmounted before?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the soft mount option. Not sure on OSX but it might be the '-s' flag on the mount command. If not, according to [this](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~salathe/osx_unix/nfsmount.html), you should try:

```
 This sets up a standard unix nfs mount, which is presumably what you want if 
 you are reading this. Note that you most likely need to run the Repair 
 Privileges utility first.

    Launch netinfo manager and authenticate
    select "mounts"
    from menubar: Directory>New Subdirectory (cmd-n)
       Enter the nfs mount path into the value field (eg tao:/home/tao/salathe.
       You can find correct root for the volume by typing df on another unix 
       system where the disk is mounted; it is the first column. You can add
       subdirectories to the path)

    from menubar: Directory->Append property enter "vfstype" in the property 
    field and "nfs" in the value(s) field.
       Append property dir with value of mounting point (eg /tao) this directory 
       must exist
    Append property opts with value -b (to background mount if it fails)
    Append value -P (NFS reserved port assignment)
    Append value -s (soft mount; mount process will fail after a certain number of tries)
    Should have something that looks like:

    Property      Value(s)
    vfstype       nfs
    dir           /tao
    name          tao:/home/tao/salathe
    opts          (-b, -P, -s)

    Save and quit
    Now you need to restart the nfs daemons. Find the pids and "kill -HUP" them. From the shell,

    % sudo -s
    % ps -aux | grep -E "nfsiod|automount"
    root      241   0.0  0.0     1276     84  ??  S      0:00.03 nfsiod -n 4
    root      242   0.0  0.0     1276     84  ??  S      0:00.00 nfsiod -n 4
    root      243   0.0  0.0     1276     84  ??  S      0:00.00 nfsiod -n 4
    root      244   0.0  0.0     1276     84  ??  S      0:00.00 nfsiod -n 4
    root      251   0.0  0.1     2392    440  ??  Ss     0:00.08 automount -m /Netwo
    root      413   0.0  0.0     1112    196 std  R+     0:00.00 grep -E nfsiod|auto
    % kill -HUP 241 242 243 244 251 [or whatever the pids]

    done!

    Note: Sometimes when the computer goes to sleep and wakes up, mounted 
    volumes are not fully accessible from Finder. They are still there at 
    command line. To fix this, use the "force quit" feature to restart Finder.
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This has been working for me for a while now - I think it's time I marked your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is definitely part of the issue. Thanks!